# Onchange not working with using 2 options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a problem with my onchange.
My JS :

```
<script>
    function brands()
{
   var brand = $('#brand').val(); 
   var area = $('#area').val(); 
    $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/arealeader/lists/' + area + '/' + brand,
  {

    brand:brand
    area:area

    },
    function(data) 
    {

    $('#listoutlet').html(data);
    }); 

}
</script>
```

and here is my html & php code

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Area Outlet</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <select class="form-control select2" id="area" name="area">
                            <option value="none">None</option>
                            <? foreach($area as $tb1){?>
                              <option value="<?=$tb1->areacode?>"><?=$tb1->Description?></option>
                            <? } ?>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Brand</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <select class="form-control" id="brand" onchange="brands()" name="brand">
                            <option value="none">None</option>
                            <? foreach($brand as $brands){?>
                              <option value="<?=$brands->BrandCode?>"><?=$brands->BrandDescription?></option>
                            <? } ?>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                            </div>
```

what i want to :

1. User choose Brand
2. User choose area
3. The result will show depends both option

I got this error from console 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: brands is not defined`

---

My js working fine if i do this

```
<script>
        function brands()
    {
       var area = $('#area').val(); 
        $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/arealeader/lists/' + area,
      {

        area:area

        },
        function(data) 
        {

        $('#listoutlet').html(data);
        }); 

    }
    </script>
```

--- I check via browser console

[image]

---

I have fixed my problem. i just simply do this

```
    I delete this -> brand:brand
    area:area
```

Comment: Is your jquery code wrapped in `$(document).ready`? Could be an issue

Comment: No it is not. I've update my question

Comment: well it's obvous your page not find `function brands()`

Comment: brand:brand area:area you should required comma here!   brand:brand,area:area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma here:

```
brand:brand,
area:area
```

Multiple values need to be separated by commas that's why it works with `area:area`.